# Cannot start Windows Azure VM programmatically

Tags: rest, azure

I'm performing REST API operation **Start Role** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157189.aspx)

In the link **https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription-id}/services/hostedservices/{service-name}/deployments/{deployment-name}/roles/{role-name}/Operations** we have replaced **{service-name}**, **{deployment-name}** and **{role-name}** with name of VM.

In result we have next message:
"`ResourceNotFound`The resource service name hostedservices is not supported."

**List Hosted Services** operation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460781.aspx) shows us that we have 2 WMs as hosted services.

**Get Role** operaion (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157193.aspx) also gives info about each of VMs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using:

{subscription-id}/services/hostedservices/{service-name}/deployments/{deployment-name}/**roles**/{role-name}/Operations

But the correct Uri is:

{subscriptionID}/services/hostedservices/{serviceName}/deployments/{deploymentName}/**roleInstances**/{roleInstanceName}/Operations

See the difference?

Comment: But in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157189.aspx we have <deployment-name>/roles/<role-name>/Operations URI

Comment: MSDN documentation is screwed up! I actually reversed engineered Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets and it is using the URI mentioned above.

Comment: And what about the request's body? Server said: "The request body's XML was invalid or not correctly specified."

Comment: Also I have found this topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg441298.aspx. But it contains only reboot operation and VM needs authorization certificate. For cloud service I can add the certificate, but not for VM!

Comment: You need to use the same Uri as for start, but you need to use `RestartRoleOperation` for the OperationType.

Comment: Yes, I used correct URI with roleInstances, and the xml body from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj157189.aspx and I have received "The request body's XML was invalid or not correctly specified.". Where I can find a valid xml body for POST?

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I was pulling my hair out. @user1696965 can you post the XML you are using (edit your question)?

Comment: At now it works for me too. It seems that start/stop service has been disabled on October 3. But on the next day I have performed request successfully. Thanks for help!

Comment: I think the "roles" (as opposed to the "roleinstances") version of the URL is correct, depending on what version of the API you are using.  When using version 2012-08-01 of the API, only "roles" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this particular operation, however a few things:

**service-name**: It should be the name of the hosted service (the one with .cloudapp.net) and what you see when you list your hosted service.

**deployment-name**: Generally speaking it's a GUID returned by Get Deployment operation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx).

**role-name**: Role name is also returned when you do a Get Deployment operation. You should use that. I'm not sure if it is same as the name of your VM.

Can you retry your operation after changing these values?

Comment: In my case all of them has one value - VM's name. I have checked it in "hosted list" and "get deployment".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deployment name is the name of the first VM I created in this cloud service. So, if I added 3 machines to the same cloud service, all of them have the same deployment name - the name of the first machine.