# The resource service name networksecuritygroups is not supported error in Azure rest call

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I am getting below error response 
"The resource service name networksecuritygroups is not supported" while calling Azure REST service 
PUT https://management.core.windows.net/subscription-id/ services/networksecuritygroups/network-security-group-name/rules/rule-name

providing proper subscription-id, network-security-group-name which is already created and a new rule-name.

Any idea please provide info.

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Aren't you missing `networking` in your resource URL? Shouldn't it be `https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription-id}/services/networking/networksecuritygroups/{network-security-group-name}/rules/{rule-name}`?

Comment: Tried that, it gives some wired xml response which contains one readable line "Endpoint not found". Not sure what does it mean. Because before setting rule in NSG I just created that NSG.

Comment: Azure API doc link. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/azure/dn913819.aspx

Comment: I see....my comment was based on the following link...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn913818.aspx

Comment: Doesnt solve the issue though, @Gaurav could you please verify the URL as you did for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708829/cannot-start-windows-azure-vm-programmatically. Thanks in advance.